# PowerShell Script to delete files after some retention period of subfolders and create a log of deleted files

Tags: powershell, delete-file

I am very newbie to the Powershell script. Dont Know much about it.
We have a folder structure of database servers and each DB has retention policy folders name as 15days , 45 days and 90 days. And in each sub folder there are 4 subfolders of full, incremental etc and each has files in it with retention period.
Need to delete files which are more than retention period in each subfolder.
Path : \sql-sharepath\DB-server\15D/45D/90D\full/Inc/partial
Can any one help ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are all at the same folder depth, you can try something like this where you just look for the retention date in the folder name, with wildcards around that:

```sh
# 15 Days
$15Days = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\sql-sharepath\DB-server15D*" -Recurse | 
  Where-Object -Property LastWriteTime -LT (Get-Date).AddDays(-15)

# log the files to delete
$15Days | Select FullName,LastWriteTime | Export-Csv -Append "\\logs\deleted.log" -NoTypeInformation

# delete
$15Days | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

And repeat for the different retention periods

The `-WhatIf` flag means it won't actually delete anything. It will just print out what it's doing and file paths, so you can figure out if it will work first

[Edit] Added `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` to include subfolders

Comment: I will definitely try and let you know the outcome of this.

`Main Path --> \sql-sharepath\

Have many DB servers --> \DB-server\`

How can we loop through all the subfolders of in DB-servers folder.

Thank you and Appreciate your help.

Comment: It should also log the files which are deleted in all the subfolders

Comment: @Yebob added requested changes. If that path won't work, then you could also use `Get-ChildItem -Path "\\server\share\*" -Filter "*15D*"`. Be careful of it grabbing too much though. You can limit it to just backup files with `-Filter *.bak` or something